# Show and Hide the status bar when button clicked:Android

Tags: android, button, statusbar

I am working around one android app while i need to show and hide the status bar when button clicked.is it possible?please help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
// Show status bar
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```